# Filter different data frame and merge the results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have different DataFrames, they have a common column (id), as the data is huge, I want to filter all DataFrames on a list of values defined in (lis) and then merge all the newly built DataFrames on a common column.
I implemented it, as follows, it is slow and have many duplicate.I am not sure if my answer is correct, can someone help me to optimize the code?

My Merge result is so bigger than dataframes size, I dont know how to find a correct merge for my data.

```
from functools import reduce
import functools as ft


df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6]
lis = ["PT08"]
dfs = []

for df in df_list:
    dfs.append(df[df['id'].isin(lis)])

df = df_list[0]
for df_ in dfs[1:]:
    dfall= df.merge(df_, on='id')
    
dfall
```

Answer (score 0):

just you can use from multi processing in python. after filtering
Parallel process for below merges
df1 df2 - df3 df4 - df5 df6
(Select the order based on you dataframes, hard merging must place this part)
then merge 3 datafrme
It can a little improve your speed